# how can i get sequential execution list of init scripts?

Tags: upstart

I write following script but it is not working during upstart,

```
start on startup exec echo "Current date:-" $(date) > /tmp/myscript.out
```

I have stored this script as `/etc/init/myscript.conf`

Please help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @wojox , thax for suggetion but i want to achieve the time stamp when upstart emits the startup event.. :(

Comment: Just a sidenote: Usually /tmp is emptied at boot. If your script writes there, and is run before that, you'll not get any output.

Comment: Thanks soulsource,  Can you help me , how to get the time stamp at start-upevent ?

Comment: I'm at it. Just found out that there's another obstacle: At the time, the startup event is triggered, the root filesystem is still readonly...

Comment: Got a working solution: http://pastebin.com/CiG9s57K - This script will write the time it is being run at in the kernel message buffer and it will therefore be listed in dmesg and syslog.

Comment: @soulsource Thank you very much for the help, its working.. :)

Comment: @soulsource  - question has been reopened - please post your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since the startup event is emitted at a very early stage in the boot process, the root filesystem is still mounted readonly, and no other filesystems are available yet, so directly writing to a file is not yet an option. Also, logging services are not yet running.

A possible workaround for these issues is to send the data that should be preserved to the kernel message buffer. By doing this, it will be available later in dmesg and it will also be copied to the syslog, once the logging daemon starts. This can be done, by sending the text to the kmsg device. A sample `.config` file excerpt could look like this:

```
start on startup

task
exec echo Upstart-Startup event at: $(date) > /dev/kmsg
```